# UITableviewCell showing old data and new data on reload

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

I have a `UITableViewCell` and I am adding `xib` in `cellForRowIndexPath` method. It works fine until I update the model and call reloadData on `UITableView`. The cell is showing new data on top of the old data, I can see the label on the old label text.

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

 let customView:CustomView = UIView.fromNib()
            userView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: y, width: Int(self.tableView.bounds.size.width-50), height: 50)
userView.label.text = data[indexPath.row]
cell.addSubview(customView:)
```

Any guesses why this could happen?

Comment: If the cell is being reused you need to clear it’s contents before using it again

Comment: I added 
 let theSubviews: Array = (cell?.contentView.subviews)!
        for view in theSubviews
        {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
but the subviews count 0 in cellForRowIndexPath

Comment: Please update your question with the `cellForRowIndexPath` code.

Comment: @PhillipMills Added. Thanks

Comment: You're adding the custom view as a subview of the cell but, in your comment, you say that you're trying to remove it from the content view instead of the cell.  You probably want to add it to the content view.

Comment: Good catch, it worked. I forgot to add contentView when adding the subview that's why the count was 0 when i tried to remove the subviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is this: since cells are reused when dequeued, you are adding a new `CustomView` to a cell that already had a `CustomView` added when dequeued previously.

One way you could handle this is to remove any existing `CustomView` from the hierarchy before creating a new one and adding it.  To do this you could add a recognizable tag to the view each time, and then look for a view with that same tag to remove during your dequeue process, like this:

```
//Remove existing view, if it exists
if let existingView = cell.viewWithTag(999) {
  //A view was found - so remove it.
  existingView.removeFromSuperview()
}
let customView: CustomView = UIView.fromNib()

//Set a tag so it can be removed in the future
customView.tag = 999
customView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: y, width: Int(self.tableView.bounds.size.width-50), height: 50)
customView.label.text = data[indexPath.row]
cell.addSubview(customView)
```

To me this feels like overkill, as it seems you should just add your customView to a custom `UICollectionViewCell` so you aren't essentially creating a custom cell on the fly, but that is just me.  If you did this you could simply dequeue your custom cell and set the text on the label without having to add more views to the hierarchy all the time.